# Можно ли говорить: выздороветь от коронавируса?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексическая-сочетаемость

***В столице выздоровели от коронавируса еще 1 186 человек*.**

Интересное дело, а я-то думала так говорить нельзя. Вот  и Михалков писал:  «Почему
Тащат валенки ему,
Меховые рукавицы,
Чтобы мог он руки греть,
Чтоб не мог он простудиться
И **от гриппа умереть»**.

Наверное, **Грамота.ру**  знает.

Вопрос № 305292. Здравствуйте! Правильно ли говорить '**выздороветь от вируса**'? Спасибо!

Ответ справочной службы русского языка: Сочетание **некорректно.**

А как же тогда правильно сказать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что пишет Грамота.ру.

**Здравствуйте! Корректно ли писать коронавирус COVID-19? Разве это не плеоназм?**

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

> Ответить на Ваш вопрос нам помогла Александра Борисова, кандидат
> химических наук, научный журналист.
>
> Коронавирус – это группа вирусов. Вирус, который беспокоит сегодня
> весь мир, – SARS-CoV-2. (Известны также коронавирус SARS-CoV,
> возбудитель атипичной пневмонии, первый случай заболевания которой был
> зарегистрирован в 2002 году; коронавирус MERS-CoV, возбудитель
> ближневосточного респираторного синдрома, вспышка которого произошла в
> 2015 году.) COVID-19 – болезнь, которую вызывает вирус SARS-CoV-2. **В
> разговорной речи всю эту группу понятий можно называть
> коронавирусом.**
>
> Сравните с названиями других вирусов и заболеваний.
>
> ВИЧ – это вирус. СПИД – это болезнь, которую вызывает ВИЧ.
>
> Грипп – это группа вирусов. Также называют и болезнь, которую
> вызывает вирус гриппа. А вот свиной грипп, птичий грипп – это уже типы
> вирусов гриппа (их еще иногда обозначают буквами и цифрами, например
> свиной грипп H1N1).
>
> Рекомендации по употреблению названий коронавирус и COVID-19 можно
> дать такие.
>
> COVID-19 корректно говорить о болезни, но не о вирусе.
> **Коронавирусом можно назвать и вирус, и болезнь (ср. пример с гриппом).**
>
> **То есть можно сказать о болезни: У него коронавирус.** А если
> нужно подчеркнуть, что речь идет о самом вирусе, – тогда правильно:
> коронавирус SARS-CoV-2.
>
> Однако нужно учитывать, что коронавирус в значении 'болезнь' – **это
> разговорное, бытовое употребление.** Сочетание  термина COVID-19 со
> словом коронавирус в бытовом значении 'болезнь' невозможно, а в
> терминологическом значении 'вирус' неправильно. Нельзя болезнь
> (комплекс симптомов) называть вирусом. Но допустимо сочетание
> коронавирусная инфекция COVID-19, потому что инфекция – это болезнь.

Получается, что в повседневной, разговорной речи можно сказать: он выздоровел от короновируса.

Однако, в других  стилях речи такое употребление неверно.

Таким образом, в приведенном вами примере ошибка.

[Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=305084)

Comment: Серж, большое спасибо за ответ. С болезнью мне теперь всё ясно. Получается, что коронавирусом  в бытовом понимании можно назвать болезнь. Но этот термин в значении «инфекционное заболевание» употребляется и в СМИ тоже. Но меня интересует еще правильность сочетания «выздороветь от болезни», я полагала,  что от болезни умирают, а не выздоравливают.  Одинаковые конструкции с разной лексикой мне кажутся странными.

Comment: Я обратила внимание на другие варианты с таким содержанием: выздороветь  после коронавируса, вылечиться от коронавируса, такие сочетания выглядят более корректно. И поэтому остается вопрос:  насколько правильно  говорить «выздороветь от болезни». Как вы думаете?

Comment: Но "выздороветь от коронавируса" встречается часто,  многие так пишут, например :https://endokrinolog.online/vyzdorovlenie-ot-koronavirusa/ Мне это сочетание напрягает слух, но вот где проверить его корректность или отсутствие корректности.

Comment: Достаточно обратиться к словарям. Стать снова здоровым; оправиться от болезни. Вы уже выздоровели? <Выздоравливать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Выздоравливание, -я; ср. В. проходило медленно. Выздоровление, -я; ср. Полное в.

Comment: Для глагола "оправиться" указано управление в словаре: ОПРАВИТЬСЯ 2. (от чего). Прийти в прежнее нормальное состояние (после болезни, несчастья, стихийного бедствия и т.п.). О. от гриппа, от контузии. А выздороветь - это уже оправиться от болезни, так зачем повторять?

Comment: Я с вами согласен. Видимо, по аналогии вылечиться от. Также при этом глаголе так и хочется употребить предлог.

Comment: *Получается, что в повседневной, разговорной речи можно сказать : он выздороветь от короновируса.* - этой фразы нет в источнике, на который вы ссылаете. Извольте не вводить людей в заблуждение своими домыслами.

Comment: behemothus, на этом форуме только вы вводите людей в заблуждение своими домыслами. Так что не надо на других клеветать.

Comment: Получается, что в повседневной, разговорной речи можно сказать : он выздороветь от короновируса. Это предложение -  мое личное мнение. Я нигде не писал, что оно из источника.

Comment: Ладно, Серж, как-нибудь потом договорим. Спасибо за беседу.

Answer (score 3):

***Выздороветь от коронавируса***  (можно предположить, что словосочетание получило широкое распространение в период эпидемии)

**Экспромт:** "Мы от гриппа не болеем, от него мы здоровеем".

**Вместо вступления**

«**Активный словарь** —  это лексика и фразеология языка, употребительная в данный период в той или иной речевой сфере».

Может быть, это и хорошая вещь, но вот в моем понимании активный словарь  – это частотный словарь. Если понимать его так, то у нас наиболее частотна **ненормативная лексика и междометия** вида «короче говоря». Образованная молодежь говорит в основном  на сленге, к нему я отношусь вполне доброжелательно, но это тоже ненормативная речь. Как составляются активные словари – понять сложно.

И еще интересно, какой процент населения вообще заглядывает в словари.  Управление в русском языке – это сложная тема, что уж там говорить. Конечно, надо  любить язык, вслушиваться в каждое слово и беречь в той мере, на которую вы лично способны. Но это всего лишь  благие пожелания, потому что людям или некогда этим заниматься, или их это просто не интересует. Так что перспективы по части правильной сочетаемости слов у **нас самые мрачные** – активный словарь наступает! Что там ничтожная горка людей против мнения масс – как говорится, против лома нет приема.

Если вы каждый день будете слышать неправильную речь, то слух притупится, а предлоги  перестанут различаться вовсе. Может,  и падежные окончания когда-нибудь отменят. Другими словами, **массы решают всё.**

**Основная часть**

1. У нас есть три интересных глагола по теме:  ***выздороветь, поправиться и оправиться.*** *Выздороветь и поправиться* – это фактически синонимы  со значением «стать здоровым, восстановить свое здоровье **после болезни**». А вот для глагола *оправиться* управление указано в словаре: *оправиться (от чего) – от гриппа*.  Значение у него – прийти в нормальное/здоровое состояние после болезни (которая в данном случае обычно **указывается**), но  смысл такой же, как и у двух других глаголов (восстановить здоровье после болезни).
2. Вы, может быть,  думаете, что активные пользователи будут во всё это вникать? Конечно же не будут! Они всё перемешают и упростят.

– Выздороветь от гриппа? Но как же так, разве можно «стать здоровым от гриппа».  Совершенно бессмысленное выражение!  Вы Грамматику-80 почитайте, там написано, что предлог ОТ выражает **активную причину**, а здесь всё наоборот,  грипп – это причина болезни, а не выздоровления.

– Это раньше так было,  а теперь всё просто: от гриппа можно *заболеть, вылечиться или … не вылечиться.* Просто, удобно и  всем нравится.

А «не всем» остается только надеяться и **обращаться к космическому разуму**:  «Куда от этого я денусь?! О, кто-нибудь, приди, нарушь…»

3. Ладно, хватит лирики, надо в Нацкорпус заглянуть: «***умереть от***» – 1430  примеров, «***выздороветь от***» – 21 пример, то есть пока единичные случаи.

Из словаря:
ПОПРАВИТЬСЯ,  5. Восстановить своё здоровье, выздороветь. ВЫЗДОРОВЕТЬ,  Стать снова здоровым; оправиться от болезни. Вы уже выздоровели? ОПРАВИТЬСЯ,  2. (от чего). Прийти в прежнее нормальное состояние (после болезни, несчастья, стихийного бедствия и т.п.). О. от гриппа, от контузии.

Answer (score 2):

Дам для разнообразия ссылку на хороший словарь. Ю.Д. Апресян в "Активном словаре русского языка" говорит следующее.

> **ВЫЗДОРАВЛИВАТЬ**, ГЛАГ; -аю, -ает; НЕСОВ; СОВ **выздороветь**.
>
> **ЗНАЧЕНИЕ**.
> *А1* выздравливает от *А2*. "Плохое физическое состояние
> существа *А1*, возникшее обычно в результате болезни *А2*, постепенно
> улучшается и *А1* становится здоровым".
>
> **УПРАВЛЕНИЕ**.
> *А1* — ИМ. *А2* — *от* РОД: *выздоравливать от тяжёлой болезни*.
> *А1* — ИМ. *А2* — *после* РОД: *выздоравливать после ангины*.
>
> *Они слышали или читали недавнее высказывание известного американского
> онголога, что если кто-нибудь тридцать лет назад сказал бы ему, что
> видел выздоровевшего от острого лейкоза, то место тому в сумасшедшем
> доме* (Л.Дурнов — известный онколог).

**Дополнение**.

Приведу, пожалуй, аннотацию к словарю Ю.Д. Апресяна, чтобы у участников форума не сложилось впечатления (по другим ответам), что это частотный словарь бреда и ошибок безграмотных русскоязычных масс.

**Дополнение 2**.

Ввиду едкой критики словаря Ю.Д. Апресяна приведу список авторов из "масс", которые были замеченны в "выздоровлениях от болезней". Сами цитаты в таком большом количестве приводить не стану — желающие легко их найдут, а остальным от них не будет пользы.

И.И. Мечников, И.А. Ефремов, А.Т. Твардовский, Н.О. Лосский, М.С. Харитонов,
К.Г. Паустовский, М.М. Пришвин, Г.С. Эфрон, А.С. Новиков-Прибой, А.С. Грин,
Д.С. Мережковский, М.Е. Салтыков-Щедрин, Н.А. Бестужев, М.И. Цветаева,
А.И. Куприн, Е. И. Замятин, М.А. Булгаков, З.Н. Гиппиус, И.А. Гончаров,
Ф.М. Достоевский, С.П. Залыгин, С.М. Третьяков.

Несколько десятков менее именитых учёных и писателей я пропустил. Да и чувствую себя неловко, противопоставляя такие фамилии "убийственному сарказму" и "оксюморону".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Аннотация вполне на уровне, а вот словарная статья напоминает пародию, как  будто она для механических людей написана. Лично мне она никаких знаний не дает и ничего  не объясняет. Да еще ошибка там: УПРАВЕНИЕ.  Почему автор считает, что именно "управение" используется в активной речи россиян (по каким источникам эта активность определяется).

Comment: @Sharon Неужели Вы впервые столкнулись с подобными словарями? Ну что ж, посмейтесь. По поводу опечатки: текст в словаре не копируется и я допустил опечатку при ручном наборе. Спасибо, исправил. Мне жаль, что из-за этой моей ошибки ухудшилось Ваше мнение о профессиональных качествах одного из лучших лингвистов современности. Кстати, я нашёл ещё несколько словарей с "выздороветь от болезни". Цитаты не привожу, поскольку считаю, что в подобных языковых заблуждениях не способны помочь никакие аргументы.

Answer (score 1):

> Сочетание некорректно.

Согласен. Абсолютно некорректно, хотя и встречается запредельно часто. Но каких только ошибок нельзя найти на просторах интернета? "Выздоровел от смерти" - и то где-то видел *)Об идее Сержа разрешить такое в разговорном стиле - см. ниже.

> А как же тогда правильно сказать?

***Излечиться от коронавируса.***

"Излечиться от чего" - это понятно, сомнений не вызывает. Но "выздороветь от"  означает совсем другое. Выздоровел от приема лекарства, например. То есть стал здоровым в резельтате каких-то действий/событий. Но стать здоровым от того, что заболел "коронавирусом" - что-то запредельное.

Что касается предложения (лично @Серж, поскольку "справка" не имеет к этому ни малейшего отношения) допустить в разговорную речь, то оно явно непродуманно.
Это из серии "выздоравливают как мухи". В цитируемом тексте говорится совсем о другом, о плеоназмах и том, насколько верно сочетание "заболел коронавирусом" и подобных, вместо "коронавирусным заболеванием ". То есть самое близкое к теме - это вопрос о замене "коронавирусная инфекция" на "коронавирус" - и такая замена действительно допустима в разговорном стиле. Тут вопросов нет. Как и, скажем, широко распространенное "у него онкология" вместо "у него онкологическое заболевание".

Но какое это все имеет отношение к "выздоровлению от"???

*) Не шучу, гугл такое знает. Правда, трудно сказать, насколько это ирония.*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А то я думала,  что только меня беспокоит это сочетание. И выражение "выздоравливают как мухи" мне тоже вспомнилось.

Comment: Да ну что вы. Не одной. Обсуждалось еще задолго до пришествия этого ковида. Не буду искать, не принципиально.

Comment: Когда в качестве аргумента приводятся какие-то "мухи", спорить очень сложно — вроде бы и с ответом не согласен, но совершенно непонятно, что можно возразить против этих "мух".

Comment: Мухи  здесь не "какие-то", а очень важные мухи. «Выздороветь от гриппа»  и «больные  как мухи выздоравливают» — это оксюморон, то есть прием, предполагающий соединение несовместимых или противоположных понятий.

Comment: @grizzly  *спорить очень сложно — вроде бы и с ответом не согласен* С Гоголем соглашаться не надо. Его надо читать. Или хотя бы смотреть в театре. *Артемий Филиппович*: ***С тех пор как я принял начальство, — может быть, вам покажется даже невероятным, — все как мухи, выздоравливают. Больной не успеет войти в лазарет, как уже здоров; и не столько медикаментами, сколько честностью и порядком.***

Comment: @Sharon *это оксюморон* - Это не просто оксюморон. Это убийственный сарказм  Есть известное выражение "мрут, как мухи [осенью]". А у Земляники (попечителя богоугодных заведений) больные "как мухи выздоравливают".

Answer (score 0):

**Как совместили несовместимое**

Это опыт словообразовательного анализа, рассчитанный на очень доброжелательных слушателей.  Поэтому, пожалуйста, не ставьте минусы.

Вернемся к нашим глаголам-синонимам: ***выздороветь, поправиться, оправиться от болезни.*** Почему глагол ***оправиться*** сочетается с предлогом ОТ, а два других глагола не сочетаются – вот что надо решить.

1. Предлог ОТ может иметь **два разных смысловых значения**, которые  были совмещены в этой теме: значение удаления  инфекции от организма (выздоровление) и  негативное  воздействие  на организм  от инфекции/со стороны инфекции (заболевание).
2. ***Оправиться от болезни*** – это привести себя в нормальное/правильное состояние после заболевания, то есть прийти в норму после отклонения от нормы.  Здесь значение удаления,  парный вариант: приставка О – предлог ОТ. Сравнить: очиститься от грязи, то есть удалить грязь.
3. Но в двух других глаголах значения **удаления нет**. ***Поправиться*** – привести себя в нормальное состояние без указания негативного фактора, приставка ПО имеет значение направленности и совершенного вида.
4. ***Здоровый – выздороветь***, метод образования приставочно-суффиксальный.   Выздороветь – это привести себя в здоровое состояние, то есть получить определенный признак. Приставка ВЫ  имеет значение **тщательности  и законченности действия.**   Согласно словарю, здоровый  –  обладающий здоровьем (только в частности не больной).  Это общее состояние, поэтому мы не говорим: *здоровый от гриппа,  стать здоровым от гриппа, то есть выздороветь от гриппа.*
5. Соответственно,  значения удаления в этой словообразовательной схеме нет. Такое значение возможно при образовании глаголов от глаголов, например:  бить – выбить (удалить)  пыль. Но при образовании глаголов от прилагательных приставка ВЫ имеет значение получения признака.
6. Но так как глаголы ***выздороветь*** и ***оправиться от болезни***  близки по значению,  глагол *выздороветь* стал по аналогии сочетаться с предлогом ОТ. Хотя такая подмена не сразу определяется на слух, но **совмещение значений** (выздороветь от болезни и умереть от болезни) – **это очень серьезная стилистическая погрешность.**

О СЛОВАРЯХ

Справедливости ради надо сказать несколько слов об авторе Активного словаря русского языка.

Апресян  Ю.Д. (род. в 1930 году), прежде всего, **выдающийся теоретик**, а тема его основных работ – **лексическая СЕМАНТИКА** (основная тема), словари синонимов  русского и английского языка нового типа, машинный перевод, компьютерная лингвистика,  семантический метаязык,  опыт интегрального описания языка (грамматика +  словарь),  общее языкознание.

Активный словарь русского языка стал выходить с 2014 года (том 1 и 2). Интересно, что значения слов в этом словаре даются **в форме развернутых аналитических толкований.** Как это выглядит, мы уже видели: «А1 выздоравливает от А2. Плохое физическое состояние существа А1, возникшее обычно в результате болезни А2, постепенно улучшается и А1 становится здоровым». Получается, что **от А2 можно выздороветь, но и заболеть**, то есть стать больным, тоже можно. Вот такой аналитический русский язык, и никаких проблем. Но всё-таки я подозреваю, что в языке всё намного сложнее – мы не роботы, роботы не мы.

**Варианты управления**  в словаре тоже присутствуют, но на чем они основаны, насколько нормативны – это неясно.  И  еще:  «Каждая такая словарная статья снабжена **обширными иллюстрациями из «Национального корпуса русского языка».** А вот иллюстрации из Нацкорпуса точно не помешали бы, но в приведенной словарной статье их нет.

Comment: *А вот иллюстрации из Нацкорпуса точно не помешали бы, но в приведенной словарной статье их нет.* — В этой статье 6 цитат из Нацкорпуса (одну я привёл в своём ответе). Выражения типа "выздороветь от болезни" в Нацкорпусе встречается намного чаще, чем Вы думаете. Просто Вы искать не умеете. Ефремов, Твардовский, Паустовский, Пришвин, Грин, Салтыков-Щедрин, Цветаева, Куприн, Булгаков, Гончаров, Достоевский и многие другие — более подробный (но далеко не полный) список авторов цитат из Нацкорпуса Вы можете найти в Дополнении к моему ответу. Задумайтесь на минутку, кому Вы себя противопоставляете.

Comment: Мне уже пора встать с ними в один ряд? Хорошо, об этом я подумаю.